# Preventing php xpath query array from splitting results

Tags: php, xpath

Each result I thought should be in the same row.  However for each class="title" the result is split up into another array row everytime a BR is encountered.  The result is supposed to be all in the same row.

[html]

```
<td class="title">
<a href="http://boguslink">bogus title</a>....<br>
here is some text
</td>
```

[php]

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = $xpath->query('//td[@class="title"]/text()');

foreach ($result as $result_row) 
{       
         echo $i.":".$result_row->nodeValue."<br />";
         $i++;
}
```

[Output]

```
 0: ....
 1: here is some text
```

When output should be

[Output]

```
 0: ....here is some text
```

Is this a bug?  If not then how do I keep the class="title" result from being split into separate rows and keep my code fast-lean as above at the same time?

EDIT:

Okay not a bug and behavior of /text().  I am able to get all inner text of that class by simply removing /text() from the xpath expression. It is just trying to figure out how to exclude the link text at this point so I only get "....here is some text".

So I need an expression that excludes the link text. First failed attempts are.

```
//td[@class="title"][not(a)] 
//td[@class="title"][not(self::a)] 
//td[@class="title"][not(@href)]
```

Comment: Solved by prodigitalson. Option 3, Grab only the text nodes and then reassemble them into a complete string. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No its not a bug. The `text()` function grabs the text nodes. If you have a `<br />` or another tag in-between text then you are making multiple nodes by necessity. Thats the way the DOM works.

> Okay, so text() does not work the way I thought it does (all innerhtml
>   in a row). I removed /text() and I just need to figure out the
>   appropriate xpath so I do not get the link text. thx

Yeah i dont think youre going to be able to do that with a single query. Basically to get the text contents of the `td` as one string you need the `nodeValue` of the `td`. But that will always include the text node(s) of the `a` as well. XPath is only going to select things based on node, thats how it works. So you either take the `td` as a node and get all the content as a string, or you filter the children of the `td` to only get the nodes you want (which were all the direct `textNode`s originally). But then youll have to reassemble them as a string.

So you have 3 options:

1. Deal with the `a` text and use `$theTd->nodeValue`
2. Remove the `a` tag from the DOM before doing `$theTd->nodeValue`
3. Grab only the text nodes and then reassemble them into a complete string

Personally i think #3 is the best option and you just need to rework your code...

```
$tdNodes = $xpath->query('//td[@class="title"]');

foreach ($tdNodes as $i => $td) 
{       
         $text = $xpath->query('./text()', $td);
         $textStr = '';

         foreach($text as $str) 
         {
            $textStr .= $str->nodeValue;
         }

         echo $i.":".$textStr."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Okay, so text() does not work the way I thought it does (all innerhtml in a row).  I removed /text() and I just need to figure out the appropriate xpath so I do not get the link text. thx

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid solution, but it might work for you... If you don't want to deal with breaks in your text, replace them with spaces or nothing in your html string before you DOM it.

Comment: Note: prodigitalson has the right answer. This is a hack suggestion. :)